# Entity Framework 6: Delete Child item for several parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

please help. I work with EntityFramework 6. Have entity:

```
public class PowerStation {

        public Guid PowerStationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Guid PowerStationTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual PowerStationType PowerStationType { get; set; }

        public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }
        public DateTime SubjectTransactionTime { get; set; }
        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

        public Guid ParticipantOremId { get; set; }
        public DateTime ParticipantOremTransactionTime { get; set; }
        public virtual ParticipantOrem ParticipantOrem { get; set; }

        public Guid? DcId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DcTransactionTime { get; set; }
        public virtual Dc Dc { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<DcLink> DcLinks { get; set; }   
        public virtual ICollection<DcPowerStationProposal> DcPowerStationProposals { get; set; }
}
```

I try to remove this entity, but get exception:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

I can try this:

```
entity = db.PowerStations
                    .Include(x => x.Equipments)
                    .Include(x => x.DcLinks)
                    .Include(x => x.DcPowerStationProposals)
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PowerStationId == entity.PowerStationId && x.TransactionTime == entity.TransactionTime);


var station = db.ParticipantOrems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParticipantOremId == entity.ParticipantOremId
                && x.TransactionTime == entity.ParticipantOremTransactionTime);
                station.PowerStations.Remove(entity);

var subject = db.Subjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SubjectId == entity.SubjectId
                && x.TransactionTime == entity.SubjectTransactionTime);
                subject.PowerStations.Remove(entity);

var dc = db.Dcs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DcId == entity.DcId
                && x.TransactionTime == entity.DcTransactionTime);
                dc.PowerStations.Remove(entity);

var type = db.PowerStationTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PowerStationTypeId == entity.PowerStationTypeId);
                type.PowerStations.Remove(entity);

db.Equipments.Local.Where(x => x.PowerStation == null).ToList().ForEach(r => Equipments.Remove(r));
db.DcLinks.Local.Where(x => x.PowerStation == null).ToList().ForEach(r => DcLinks.Remove(r));
db.PowerStationProposals.Where(x => x.PowerStation == null).ToList().ForEach(r => DcPowerStationProposals.Remove(r));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna delete whole PowerStation you should delete migrations and reupdate it

Comment: I want remove row in database, not table.

Comment: I didn't check the code but it says you your table connected other tables with foreign keys and they are non nullable, make them nullable or delete connected rows?

Comment: i tried delete connected rows without cascade delete, not help. Nullable - it's problem, but i tried - not result.

Comment: execuse me, nullable help... but I think, it's not correct for required related.